# Automate bundle copying/linking of MarketingCloudSDK.bundle in SPM

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilepush, ios, mobilepush-ios

While upgrading from MarketingCloudSDK 7.x to 8.x, I noticed these instructions:

> Manually pull in the Resources/MarketingCloudSDK.bundle from the
> sources folder in the Mobile Push SPM and link it with the binary in
> build phase.

Now - that's pretty inconvenient. While with CocoaPods it was still pretty common to push the installed Pods to GIT repositories, SPM was a great candidate to step away from that. However by having to copy the bundle manually, this actually increases the work of maintaining the version up-to-date and might even corrupt versions by having an automatically updated SPM package, but an outdated bundle. I guess this could be automated, but again, that's a really inconvenient task to put on all customers.

So the question is - is there any way to automate this and in best case avoids to copy the bundle into the app space?

And while I'm no SPM expert, would the support for bundle resources starting with SPM 5.3 be able to solve this issue for everyone?

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 0):

@Jerrot the one way to fix the problem is to pull the exact version through SPM instead of the next major or minor one.

I will not recommend that solution but in the current environment this is the only viable solution with the SPM implementation by Salesforce dev team

we can only request the team for the automate resource pulling solution from the team.

Also, they don't have the issue tracking system on GitHub. we can only rely on this platform for more updates.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of this to avoid update corruption, but still the manual copying/linking should not be necessary at all. I noticed that CocoaPods support is still there though, so I sticked to that for now until the SPM support is properly fixed.