# Crashing after migrating to 8.0.0 with uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException'

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios, mobilepush-ios

After Migrating the current mobile push SDK (iOS ) to the latest version, App started crashing on the launch with uncaught exception

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'NSFetchRequest could not locate an NSEntityDescription for entity name 'SFMCEventConfigurationEntity'`

Comment: Upgrade to 8.0.8.

Answer (score 1):

I have come across this scenario from another user. The solution that worked was to replace this file every time you upgrade after 8.0 which is mentioned in [doc](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/get-started/get-started-migration.html)

> Manually pull in the Resources/MarketingCloudSDK.bundle from the sources folder in the Mobile Push SPM and link it with the binary in build phase.

Answer (score 1):

Please pull the MarketingCloudSDK.bundle file from sources folder in SPM to the application to have the latest changes. This will resolve the issue

Thanks
Prakashini

Comment: Already done that. but this is not a solution if you have to do everything manually, and they have very less documentation

Comment: https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/get-started/get-started-migration.html -> This document clearly states that the dependencies should be added. Recommend to follow the document as few steps are mandatory. 

Thanks

Comment: there is nothing mentioned about the updating bundle resource every time.

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/369926/automate-bundle-copying-linking-of-marketingcloudsdk-bundle-in-spm/387014#387014 see my comment there